# Can the comparison of multiple contiguous unsigned integers be optimized in a safe manner?

Tags: c++, reinterpret-cast, type-punning

In GCC 13.2 and Clang 18.0.1 using `-O3`, the generated assembly for `operator <` of a tuple of four `std::uint16_t` objects is less than impressive (pun intended).  Two other implementations using `reinterpret_cast` and type punning both produce optimized assembly.

**EDIT**: Since this question is already getting downvotes, I'd like to point out that the default assembly uses 3 conditionals, which is quite impactful when this code is being run in a high-performance loop.  Both other implementations have zero branches.

Question 1: Are these implementations correct?

Question 2: If not, what conditions are required to guarantee correctness?

Question 3: Assuming there is a test for correctness that can be evaluated at compile time, why doesn't the compiler simply output the optimized assembly?

```
#include <cstdint>
#include <tuple>
#include <bit>

using TupleU16 = std::tuple<std::uint16_t, std::uint16_t, std::uint16_t, std::uint16_t>;

bool less(TupleU16 lhs, TupleU16 rhs) {
    return lhs < rhs;
}

constexpr bool canSafelyUseTypePunning() {
    TupleU16 t;
    std::uint16_t* val0 = &std::get<0>(t);
    std::uint16_t* val1 = &std::get<1>(t);
    std::uint16_t* val2 = &std::get<2>(t);
    std::uint16_t* val3 = &std::get<3>(t);

    if constexpr (std::endian::native == std::endian::little) {
        return sizeof(TupleU16) == 8 &&
            (val0 - val3) == 3 && (val0 - val2) == 2 && (val0 - val1) == 1;
    }
    else if constexpr (std::endian::native == std::endian::big) {
        return sizeof(TupleU16) == 8 &&
            (val3 - val0) == 3 && (val2 - val0) == 2 && (val1 - val0) == 1;
    }
    else {
        return false;
    }
}

bool less2(TupleU16 lhs, TupleU16 rhs) { // cannot be constexpr
    static_assert(canSafelyUseTypePunning());
    auto* lhsp = reinterpret_cast<const std::uint64_t*>(&lhs);
    auto* rhsp = reinterpret_cast<const std::uint64_t*>(&rhs);
    return *lhsp < *rhsp;
}

bool less3(TupleU16 lhs, TupleU16 rhs) { // can be constexpr
    static_assert(canSafelyUseTypePunning());
    union U {
        std::uint64_t u64;
        TupleU16 tu16;
    };
    return U{.tu16 = lhs}.u64 < U{.tu16 = rhs}.u64;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

No, that's

1. an aliasing violation causing undefined behavior, because you access the `std::tuple` object through a pointer of a different type and many compilers actually do make use of the aliasing rule for optimization (although there are often options to disable these optimizations)
2. implementation-dependent, because there is no guarantee about `std::tuple`s memory layout at all and there are in fact `std::tuple` implementations which order elements in different orders. They are not even guaranteed to be contiguous in memory.

The reason that `std::tuple`'s `operator<` is suboptimal for your use case is probably that it guarantees that the lexicographically next element is only accessed if the previous element's comparison hasn't been conclusive yet. That means that it gives extra guarantees in the case that another thread modifies other elements of the tuple.

It seems that you don't need that guarantee and would prefer a more performant implementation. If you need that, implement a `std::tuple`-equivalent with these requirements and layout assumptions you need in mind yourself and for the comparison use `std::bit_cast<uint64_t>` instead of `reinterpret_cast` to get defined behavior (or equivalently `std::memcpy` to a local `uint64_t` variable). Also, if all element types of the tuple are equal, then `std::array` would be enough (but it has the same `operator<` performance issue).

Comment: The point about multiple threads accessing different elements of the tuple is something I had not considered.  Of course, you are correct.

Comment: tuples order is indeed the biggest issue. Due to how tuple is generally implemented, order is way off what one would expect, on pretty much every compiler. strict aliasing does not apply to some (MSVC), or can be turned off; but no way to make tuple be close to standard-layout/ordered.